# ListView.builder and Image together in a Row in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Idea is to put a `ListView.builder` and an `Image` together side by side horizontally.
So, I put the `ListView.builder` and the `Image` in a Row.

This `Row` is inside a `ListView` which has other children too.

The problem is that before I introduced the `Row`, the `ListView.builder` was showing up properly. Now with `Row`, `ListView.builder` and an `Image` are NOT being shown.

There are no errors, just the contents are invisible.

```
                                        Row(
                                          children: <Widget>[                                          
                                            ListView.builder
                                            (
                                              shrinkWrap: true,
                                              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                              itemCount: list3.length,

                                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) 
                                              {
                                                return new ListView
                                                          (
                                                            shrinkWrap: true,
                                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                                                            children: <Widget>
                                                            [                                                       
                                                              ListTile(
                                                                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                                                                            radius: 6.0,
                                                                            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                                                          ),
                                                                  title : Text(list3[Index], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 25,),)
                                                              ),
                                                            ]
                                                          );
                                              },                                          
                                            ),
                                            Expanded(
                                                  child: Image(
                                                    image: NetworkImage('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl.jpg'),
                                                    height: 15,
                                                    width: 15,
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                  )
                                                ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `ListView.builder` with `Expanded`.

Answer (score 1):

The `ListView` is inside a `Row` and needs a width, so that the other element can expand in the remaining area. So wrap it inside a `SizedBox`.

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 300,
  child: ListView.builder(),
)
```

Comment: Thanks to you too.